# Plank texture in mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing

I am modelling a wooden house and I'm having some trouble modeling the outside of the house which is covered in vertically aligned planks.

I have tried using the displacement map from a downloaded texture but it doesn't really work. I think the easiest way would be to model the mesh with loop cuts and then extrude every other surface to make a kind of plank texture.

But the problem here is the top of the house is a triangular prism and I can't figure out how to get the loop cuts to align vertically... Any thoughts and ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Need more geometries if you want to use displacement

Comment: hello, some pictures would help to understand your problem

Comment: Here are some photos of the shape of the house and an example of the kind of texture I am looking for.

https://ibb.co/rsy6zR7

https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/los-paneles-de-madera-del-viejo-rojo-grunge-usados-como-fondo-30007658.jpg

Comment: so there are several ways to do it, depending what's your final goal, if you plan to have close-up shots, etc. You can simply unwrap your mesh, give each face the texture you show, and also create a height map from the same pictures and use it to give your planks a bit of fake 3D...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of cutting each plank (which you can do, depending on the level of realism that you want to give to your object) you could use your image to create a bump map, so that it creates a bit of 3D feeling:

- Seam your object:

[image]

- Unwrap:

[image]

- Create a height map from your current wood plank picture, with a soft like Crazy Bump or with a site like [this one](https://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/) :

[image]

- Create this kind of node setup, plug the *Bump* node into the *Normal* input socket of the *Principled BSDF*:

[image]

- Here is what it gives:

[image]

- Once you've done that you can still create additional edge loops and move the planks the way you want, or even extrude, cut holes, etc:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Moonboots I love you! :) But now is there a way to use this height map to actually change the mesh? If I try to plug the bump node into the displacement of the material output and put Cycles render settings to "bump and displacement" everything just freaks out. Or would I have to, as you say, extrude the planks "manually" ?

Comment: If you want a real displacement, meaning the vertices to be really displaced, you need to give your mesh enough topology, which means subdivide it a lot or giving it a high subdivided Subdivision Surface modifier, this would be a bit crazy because it would be a very heavy file, unless you plan to 3D print? In that case of course you need real displacement but you need to do it through the Displace modifier I guess

Comment: Ok thank you, yes my thought was to 3d print it. I'll try to subdivide it a lot and see if it works, or else maybe I'll try to get it printed without the texture. Anyways thank you so much!:))

Comment: In that case you'll need to use the Displace modifier and choose the Coordinates > UV